# Проблема с vk-api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, pip

Гуглил пока идеи для запросов не закончились, внятного ответа так и не нашёл.
Python 3.8, чистый,кроме модуля vk-api других не стоит. Кто сталкивался с этим, подскажите что делать

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vk_api.longpoll'; 'vk_api' is not a package`

Comment: Переименуйте файл со скриптом. Название файла не должно пересекаться с именами используемых модулей.

Comment: Проблема оказалась именно в названии файла со скриптом. имя файла совпало с именем модуля. Спасибо Михаил!

Answer (score 1):

попробуй импортировать вот так

```py
import vk_api.vk_api

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotEventType
```

не longpoll,а bot_longpoll